# VBA Return string value with exact 11 letters

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to create macro which will return me value of transaction ID which is in string. String contains name of transactions, type, ID and fund name. There also many spaces and "-". So far I have tried with `Split()` but string is always different and it brings mislead to macro. There is value which is always stale and its transaction ID which string length is always 11. So I want macro to find value with length 11 and return it to me. Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! It would be really useful, if you give a few examples. E.g.: your input and expected output.

Comment: Show what you have tried, your code, and what you expect. The answer seems to be in split.

Comment: input example: "AAAAA and BBBBB IIOO 16IIOOBBKK5 3F3W.xls" and I want output "16IIOOBBKK5", but there is always another "space" between words and "-" so 'Split()' going crazy and 5th value is always different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for the input you have provided.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function return_me11(str) As String

    Dim my_str      As String
    Dim my_arr      As Variant
    Dim my_val      As Variant

    my_str = Replace(str, " ", "-")

    my_arr = Split(my_str, "-")

    For Each my_val In my_arr
        If Len(my_val) = 11 Then
            return_me11 = my_val
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next my_val

    return_me11 = "No good input"

End Function
```

Comment: So far it worked. Thanks! Will update if anything change :)

Comment: A possible mistake is if you have more than 1 11 length value. Then it would return the first one found.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current code for Split()

```
            strLen = Len(FileName)

            strFullName = FileName

            strName = Left(strFullName, strLen - 4) '4 is because of .xls

            strLastName = RTrim(Mid(strName, InStr(strName, " ")))
            text_string = Right(strLastName, 18)

            WrdArray() = Split(text_string)

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = WrdArray(1)
```